# Elasticsearch returns all results with Should and term query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to execute the following query in Elasticsearch

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE feed_id =1 AND brand='Samsung' OR brand='Apple iPhone'`

I used this JSON query for that

``

```
"bool" : {



 "should":[
    {
        "multi_match":
            {
            "query":"LG",
            "operator":"and",
            "fields":"brand"
            }
    },

        {
        "multi_match":
            {
            "query":"Samsung",
            "operator":"and",
            "fields":"brand"
            }
    },

    {
        "multi_match":
    {
        "query":"Nokia",
        "operator":"and",
        "fields":"brand"
    }
    }


    ],



     "filter": {
      "bool": { 
          "must": [

              { "term": { "feed_id":1}}
          ]

      }
    }

}``
```

This returns all the results..

This is my mapping

`"model": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "autocomplete": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete"
              },
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }`

However when i remove the "filter" term i get the desired results.

What is wrong with my Query?

I use ES 5.0

Comment: Can you provide full mappings included with mappings of `brand` and `feed_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Don't think you need `multi_match` as you are searching on a single field.

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "term": {
              "feed_id": 1
           }
        },
        {
           "terms": {
              "brand": [
                 "LG",
                 "Samsung",
                 "Nokia"
              ]
           }
        }
       ]
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you,But how can i achieve the same result for exact matching? I have the same issue then.

Comment: @erwinnandpersad. Please have a look at the edited answer

Comment: thanks @Rich, when i change the field to Model.keyword, then it doesn't work on a sentence. For example "Galaxy S7" returns no records

Comment: Please share the mapping. `GET index/type/_mapping`

Comment: you sure u have a document whose `feed_id` is 1 and model is `Galaxy s7`

Comment: Yeah... i double checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144094/discussion-between-richa-and-erwinnandpersad).

Answer (score 0):

It works now:

I added the minimum_should_match filter, and now it works..

See query if someone run into the same issue

`

```
    {

        "multi_match":
            {
            "query":"Nokia",
            "operator":"and",
            "fields":"brand"
            }
    },

        {

        "multi_match":
            {
            "query":"Wifi",
            "operator":"and",
            "fields":"name"
            }
    },

    {
        "multi_match":
    {
        "query":"LG K10",
        "operator":"and",
        "fields":"name"
    }
    }


    ],
    "minimum_should_match":"1"

}
```